# Numeric password input that only takes 1 value from 0 to 9

Tags: c#, blazor

Trying to create an input field that will only accept one character from 0 to 9. I don't want to use validation for this (so the user can only enter a single number no matter what they try)

I tried

```
<input type="text" size="1" maxLength="1" inputmode="numeric" />
```

However this still allows for alpha characters.

Ideally I'd like to get this working with password input too

```
<input type="password" size="1" maxLength="1" inputmode="numeric" />
```

Comment: _"The inputmode global attribute is an enumerated attribute that **hints** at the type of data that might be entered by the user while editing the element or its contents."_ (emphasis by me). So, this attribute won't help you, here. You may find a ui control framework that provides a control that is capable of that. May I ask why you despise using validation?

Comment: @Fildor I don't despise validation, I've just never encountered a site (think banking app) that would allow you to put alpha values into a PIN field

Comment: Ah, I see. So you want the Control to not accept anything other than [0..9] as input in the first place. I guess pressing something like "a" should simply be ignored then?

Comment: @Fildor yes, Ahmed's answer below seems to work well (I had no idea I could just put JS in like that!). Although as you point out, it allows for negatives/decimals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly use the numeric type of html:

> https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_number.asp

Or you can control keyboard events with javascript.

```
<input type="text" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' />
```

Comment: AFAIK "number" can still take negative values and floating point. Like "-5.68".

Comment: Exactly. OP wants the field to _only accept [0..9]_. So that's not an "or". He _must_ check on input and filter as your answer suggests but not as an alternative.

Comment: @Fildor with the `maxlength` of 1 it seems work as I'd like it to

Comment: Ah, so your "PIN" has only 1 single digit? OK, your choice :) @p3tch

Comment: you can control charCode of each letter entered by the keyboard (onkeypress)

Comment: @Fildor 4 separate inputs that auto focus one after another (seemed easier than 1 input that looks like 4 boxes). Blame the UI/UX department for that

Comment: @p3tch Ok, that makes more sense. UX - wise, I don't think it is too bad actually. It may even turn out to be easier for you than using one element and make sure it complies to the requirement.

Comment: This code didn't work for you?   <input type="text" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'  />

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mvc you can create ModelView with RegEx. like following,

```
public class ValidationViewModel
{
    [StringLength(1, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 1)]
    [RegularExpression("^[0-9]$", ErrorMessage = "Only sigle number allowed between 0-9")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

On View,

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, "Password:")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "error-message" })
}
```

Make sure you have jqueryval referenced,

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```